# Compute a point on a given quartic (fourth-order, not quadratic) bezier curve

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, bezier

I'm searching for an algorithm that returns a point on a quartic bezier (2D), given:
A. Parameter t of [0,1]
B. The 5 points that make a quartic bezier curve:

- P0 - Start point
- P1, P2, P3 - Control points 1, 2 and 3
- P4 - End point

Searching the net I couldn't find any algorithm, just nice visual applets, e.g.:
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Higher-order_curves)

I will implement using javaScript, if it somehow matters.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the very Wikipedia article you found there is a chapter *Generalization* of Bézier curves for any degree n. In the [explicit definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition) section there is even an example for `n=5`:

[image]

Comment: That's sextic form. The pyramid should be 1, 4, 6, 4, 1 and the fourth order curve should be to the power 4.  You'll see you have 6 control points.

Answer (score 4):

The De Casteljau algorithm will help you here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm